# SSH Tor Hidden Service on Pi3 - Cannot create hidden service directory

Tags: configuration, onion-services, raspbian

I'm pretty confused by this. Took a little learning on my desktop but it was a completely different issue. I just got my Pi 3 setup, installed tor (`sudo apt-get install tor`) as well as everything tor-like given as packages.

I wanted to be able to SSH into my Pi and remotely administer some of my home computers. I thought this would be simple. I placed the following into my `torrc` file:

```
HiddenServiceDir /var/lib/tor/hidden_service/ssh/
HiddenServicePort 22 127.0.0.1:22
```

So in my logs I have:

```
<<date>> [warn] Error creating directory /var/lib/tor/hidden_service/ssh/: No such file or directory
```

So if I create these I get the same log entry. After `sudo chown -R debian-tor:debian-tor /var/lib/tor/hidden_service` I get the same entry. The permissions are `drwxr-sr-x` on the `hidden_service` directory. This was a problem before on my desktop (permissions to lax). I removed the sticky bit... no change... I changed permissions to `drwx------` ... at that point tor seemed to not even work. No logs, no nothing. (Not sure if the missing log file was due to `AvoidDiskWrites 1`)

I'm not sure how to address this.

Answer (score 1):

I feel a little silly about this but I found an answer. I'm not sure how it differed from my approach. This is taken from https://gk2.sk/running-ssh-on-a-raspberry-pi-as-a-hidden-service-with-tor/

```
export SERVICE_DIR=/var/lib/tor/sshd/
mkdir $SERVICE_DIR
chmod 700 $SERVICE_DIR
chown debian-tor.debian-tor $SERVICE_DIR
```

Checked with the following as per [How to check if Tor is working and debug the problem on CLI?](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/12678/how-to-check-if-tor-is-working-and-debug-the-problem-on-cli):

```
curl --socks5 localhost:9050 --socks5-hostname localhost:9050 -s https://check.torproject.org/ | cat | grep -m 1 Congratulations | xargs
```

I can only think my sticky bit manipulation caused a problem. I did change the period to colon in the `chown` command.